# What will be the impact on data if I dynamically scale up/down the AzureSQL database?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

Currently, I'm using business critical tier for AzureSQL with 20 VCores. I wanted to downgrade it with 2 VCores when the database is not in use. Will there be any impact on data quality?

I tried the below code to scale up/down

```
 Set-AzSqlDatabase -ResourceGroupName "<ResourceGroupName>" -DatabaseName "<testServer>" -ServerName "test.database.windows.net"   -VCore 20   ---For upgrading

 Set-AzSqlDatabase -ResourceGroupName "<ResourceGroupName>" -DatabaseName "<testServer>" -ServerName "test.database.windows.net"   -VCore 2   ---For downgrading
```

It worked for me. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of transactions may get rolled back during scale up/down.

Changing the service tier or compute size of a single database mainly involves the service performing the following steps:

**Create new compute instance for the database**

A new compute instance for the database is created with the requested service tier and compute size. For some combinations of service tier and compute size changes, a replica of the database must be created in the new compute instance which involves copying data and can strongly influence the overall latency. Regardless, the database remains online during this step, and connections continue to be directed to the database in the original compute instance.

**Switch routing of connections to new compute instance**

Existing connections to the database in the original compute instance are dropped. Any new connections are established to the database in the new compute instance. For some combinations of service tier and compute size changes, database files are detached and reattached during the switch. Regardless, the switch can result in a brief service interruption when the database is unavailable generally for less than 30 seconds and often for only a few seconds. If there are long running transactions running when connections are dropped, the duration of this step may take longer in order to recover aborted transactions. Accelerated Database Recovery can reduce the impact from aborting long running transactions.

Please refer to link [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-single-database-scale) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Not really, you will be throttled a little. There is also a short delay (2 - 3) mins while the scaling provision takes place.